# SQL Join to view

Tags: php, mysql

everyone I your all great. I am having trouble to structure the SQL to join beauticians to be displayed in the same beauticians bootstrap view. I want to simply fix the sql structured lines of code. It is appearing with No data available in table.

```
<?php   

require_once 'core.php';


$sql = "SELECT appointments.appointment_id, appointments.a_name, appointments.a_status, beautician.b_firstname
FROM appointments 
INNER JOIN beautician
ON appointments.beautician_id = beautician.beautician_id
WHERE appointments.a_status = 1";




$result = $connect->query($sql);

$output = array('data' => array());

if($result->num_rows > 0) { 

 // $row = $result->fetch_array();
 $active = ""; 

 while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $appId = $row[0];
    // active 
    if($row[7] == 1) {
        // activate member
        $active = "<label class='label label-success'>Available</label>";
    } else {
        // deactivate member
        $active = "<label class='label label-danger'>Not Available</label>";
    }

    $button = '<!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAppModel" onclick="editApps('.$appId.')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeMemberModal" onclick="removeApps('.$appId.')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Remove</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </div>';




    $beautician = $row[9];
    $services = $row[10];
$customers = $row[8];


    $output['data'][] = array(      
        $row[1],
        $row[3], 
            $row[4], 
            $row[5],
            $row[6],
            $beautician,    
            $customers,
            $services,

        $activeApps,
        $button
        );  
 } // /while 

} // if num_rows

$connect->close();

echo json_encode($output);
```

Database

```
 CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
      `appointment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `a_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `a_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;





CREATE TABLE `beautician` (
  `beautician_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beautician_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_availability` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your DB scheme is correct here? `appointments.beautician_id` doesn't exist. That also should throw an error.

Comment: I still cannot see any data, help is appreciated

Comment: Use error reporting, add the DB scheme, or explain the relationship